# Can you raise i to an irrational power

Tags: complex-analysis

Can you raise the imaginary number i to a power that is an irrational number?

Comment: Sure... why not?

Comment: though one gets infinitely many numbers as the answer, ($e^{(1+4k)\theta \pi i/2  }, k \in \mathbb Z$) so one has to be careful when choosing one

Comment: - Yes, we can ! -

Comment: Why not? You may do anything you wish, but at what cost; and to what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

$$(e^{i(\pi/2+2k\pi)})^x=e^{ix(\pi/2+2k\pi)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $c \in \mathbb{C}$ arbitrarily. One might define $i^c := e^{\ln(i^c)} = e^{c \ln(i)} = e^{c \cdot \frac{i\pi}{2}}$, which works. There is a catch though: this makes use of the logarithm, which is not nicely defined on the entire complex plane. The set of all 'reasonable' outcomes for $i^c$ would be $e^{ic \cdot \left(\frac{ \pi}{2} + 2k\pi  \right)}$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence, it is not uniquely defined. This problem already arises when taking rational powers of $i$ though, so nothing's really changed.